# Where are these logs? Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Tags: android, logging, gradle

In my Android project, I go `gradle build --stacktrace` and receive the following stacktrace:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.mergeManifestsForApplication(AndroidBuilder.java:576)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeManifests.doFullTaskAction(MergeManifests.java:74)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:82)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:163)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:115)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:90)
    ... 20 more
```

Does anybody know where the mentioned logs are?

Comment: Check Gradle Console in Android Studio on the bottom right corner.

Comment: I might not be using Android Studio. What's that file's name and path that this window is showing?

Comment: I know this question is almost a year old, but in case someone finds this (like me) running gradle with --debug option pretty much spits the info you might be looking for, without needing to find where those logs are.